# finding the most reliable covariate for replicates

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, inference, ecology

I am working with garden bird data from the British Trust of Ornithology (BTO), and the way I have organised the data is in a long-format, where I have combined the habitat metric with the bird values by their locality id, which is essentially the individual whom took the reading for counts of birds and their garden type.

Now, there are mutiple habitat types inputted as a value, denoted by the codes, however when I place the format into a long-format, it looks something like this:

```
  locality_id garden_type wren pigeon rook
1    LOC_ID_1           X    5      1    5
2    LOC_ID_1           A    5      2    4
3    LOC_ID_1           C    5      3    3
4    LOC_ID_1           B    5      4    2
5    LOC_ID_1           N    5      5    1
```

The values are replicated for each garden type by the same locality id (let's assume this is in the same week observations were made).

What is the best approach to tackling this statistically? Is there a statistical test that allows me to take the value 5 from wren (as its replicated), and evenly distribute it among the other 5 habitats, is this an acceptable approach considering that the values came from the same person, whom inputted different habitat types although its from the same sample space?

Are there models that can predict where the value most likely came from, so the total value is distributed something like this:

```
  locality_id garden_type wren 
1    LOC_ID_1           X    3     
2    LOC_ID_1           A    1      
3    LOC_ID_1           C    1      
4    LOC_ID_1           B    0     
5    LOC_ID_1           N    0
```

Given that on the conditional I may require further information to suggest that it is likely to be in this habitat, to back up the test? something like, vegetation?

Comment: What is BTO? ???

Comment: I'm finding it really hard to understand your data - can you explain the final table please? There is a single locality, with five garden_types, but what do the values under 'wren' represent?  Are they habitat_types? What's wrong with them all being 5?